# Dictionary file manager class

Tags: c++, dictionary

The dictionary class loads entries from a file and then can perform operations on them. The dictionary class then stores the entries back into the file.

I would like to know the best way to check if the arguments to my dictionary member functions are valid terms/definitions.  I have thought of two possible solutions, but I am open to any other solutions.  I could either check the arguments passed in to the functions or make a term and definition class and and have the class check instead.

The reason why I want to distinguish strings from terms/definitions is so that I can read them from a file without having to encounter cases where definitions do not end in periods or other cases caused by human error.

Here is my code as it stands now.

dictionary.cpp

```
#include "dictionary.h"

//*** @TODO: What constitutes a term/definition ***

bool dictionary::search_term(const std::string& term){
    for(auto& it: entries){
        if(it.first != term);
        else return true;
    }return false;
};

bool dictionary::erase_entry(const std::string& term){
    if(search_term(term)){
        entries.erase(term);
        return true;
    }else return false;
};

bool dictionary::define_term(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition){
    if(search_term(term)){
        entries[term] = definition;
        return true;
    }else return false;
};

bool dictionary::write_entry(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition){
if(!search_term(term)){
    entries[term] = definition;
        return true;
    }else return false;
};

inline bool exists (const std::string& name) {
   struct stat buffer;   
   return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}

bool dictionary::ofs_entries(const std::string& path){
    std::string file = (path + title);
    std::ofstream ofs(file.c_str());
    if(!ofs) return false;
    for(auto& it: entries){
        ofs << it.first << ": " << it.second << '\n';
    }ofs.close();
};

bool dictionary::ifs_entries(const std::string& path){
    std::string file = (path + title);
    if(!exists(file)) return false;
    std::ifstream ifs(file.c_str());
    if(!ifs) return false;
    std::string entry;
    while(true){
        //read entries
        if(!ifs.eof()) break;
    }return true;
};
```

dictionary.h

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class dictionary{
   public:
        dictionary(const std::string& title, const std::string& definition = "")
            : entries{{title, definition}}, title(title){;};

        bool write_entry(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition = "");
        bool define_term(const std::string& term, const std::string& definition);

        bool erase_entry(const std::string& term);
        bool search_term(const std::string& term); 

        bool ofs_entries(const std::string& path);
        bool ifs_entries(const std::string& path);
    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::string> entries;
        std::string title;
};

#endif//DICTIONARY_H
```

Comment: You may want to stop and think on something if you haven't already: How do you intend to tell terms from definitions if you cannot trust the user to input terms and definitions into your database in such a manner that you cannot tell them apart?

Comment: I would have separate definitions of what a term is and what a definition is.

Comment: The user may enter entries directly into the file, but I will use this class to make a program that allows the user to create/modify dictionaries.  This program would check if the user has entered an invalid term/definition.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I must point out that, you used std::map, but you implement search_item by yourself, you don't know std::map::find()?

Then let's talk about your solution.
If your dictionary has few items, your solution is OK.
Otherwise, how could you hold all definitions for items in memory?
So, I give you two possible solutions:

1. use database, MySQL(big one), Sqlite(lite one)
2. save definitions in a seperated file, just read out offset for each, and map offsets to items.(means implement what the database do by yourself).

Comment: Storing the definitions in a separate file is genius, but what do you mean by, "Otherwise, how could you hold all definitions for items in memory?".

Comment: I mean ' you could but you should not' in fact.